# parsing data from log using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I want to extract machineId userId origReqUri,filename,mime,size,checksum as comma-separated from this log pattern. Any awk command to do it?

```
test1.1/test.log.2020-07-14-20:2020-07-14 20:47:44,239 [http--1594759553405 sessionId:4567 nodeId:node-1  machineId:31656 userId:2540397 origReqUri:/test1/batch] INFO  com.test.company  - [RETURN INFO - RETURN]  - TRACK_PREPROCESSED_DATA_POPULATION: Populated test_doc_version entry for doc version [1130783_1_0] with data from test_doc_metadata. File name: [09014b3080135f44.doc]. Mime type: [application/msword]. Content size: [100352]. MD5 checksum: [7ef30e834107990c95c7e53f7b6f6ee6].    [source:]
```

I tried

```
grep machineId:31656 test.1/test.log.2020-07-14-* |grep "Populated test_doc_version entry" | awk machineId |awk origReqUri
```

Comment: one thing I can offer in 30 seconds may help, try `awk '/machineID|origReqUri/` . Good luck.

Comment: And what is the expected output? What you tried is far from a valid attempt, it makes little sense.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use AWK, but I would resolve your problem using mostly SED and GREP, like this:

```
sed s/': '/':'/g input | sed s/' '/\\n/g | grep 'machineId\|userId\|origReqUri\|name\|type\|size\|checksum' | sed 's/\[\|\]\|\.//g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/name/filename/g' | sed 's/type/mime/g' | sed 's/.$//'
```

ps.: "input" is the name of the file where I wrote the input.
The result for the provided input is:

```
machineId:31656,userId:2540397,origReqUri:/test1/batch,filename:09014b3080135f44doc,mime:application/msword,size:100352,checksum:7ef30e834107990c95c7e53f7b6f6ee6
```

It is probably not the best solution and we can certainly make it smaller and more beautiful, but I hope it helps you.

There's another solution, simpler and way more readable. You could do like this:

```
tr -s ' :[]' ' ' < input | cut -d ' ' -f 12,14,16,39,43,47,51
```

In here, it's not comma-separated. I guess it's better not to use commas since they are in the list of special symbols.

The result for this one is:

```
31656 2540397 /test1/batch 09014b3080135f44.doc application/msword 100352 7ef30e834107990c95c7e53f7b6f6ee6
```

Comment: Quotes go **around** a script (`sed 's/: /:/g'`), not inside a script (`s/': '/':'/g`). Almost any time you're using multiple calls to tools with multiple pipes just to manipulate text (and certainly when it's 6 seds, 1 grep, 1 tr, and 7 pipes!) you should be using awk instead. The output of `tr '\n' ','` is no longer a POSIX text file (text files must end in `\n`) and so what any given tool afterwards will do with that as input is undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what `it's better not to use commas since they are in the list of special symbols` means - there's nothing special about a comma.